# TSQL Query Inserting data from xPath

Tags: sql-server, xml, t-sql, stored-procedures, xpath

I am using SQL Server 2012 and trying trying to insert data into multiple tables from an XML string containing the data. The issue and confusion stems from the XML containing multiple nodes so its not just a single record at a time.

Due to this, I am using the output method to insert the data along with the Identity so I know the result of each of the records it inserts.

My problem is due to the structure of the XML string, it is not inserting all of the data it needs to.

Here is the block of code I am working with along with a SQL Fiddle:

Fiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/d41d8/24236

```
    DECLARE @xml xml = '<root>
   <trainingEventID>572</trainingEventID>
   <segment>
      <segmentDate>03/03/2015</segmentDate>
      <hours>4</hours>
      <details>
         <locale>653</locale>
         <teammates>3</teammates>
         <leaders>4</leaders>
      </details>
      <details>
         <locale>655</locale>
         <teammates>44</teammates>
         <leaders>55</leaders>
      </details>
      <details>
         <locale>657</locale>
         <teammates>55</teammates>
         <leaders>66</leaders>
      </details>
      <trainers>
         <trainer>
            <empID>User12341</empID>
         </trainer>
      </trainers>
   </segment>
   <segment>
      <segmentDate>03/04/2015</segmentDate>
      <hours>4</hours>
      <details>
         <locale>653</locale>
         <teammates>3</teammates>
         <leaders>4</leaders>
      </details>
      <details>
         <locale>655</locale>
         <teammates>44</teammates>
         <leaders>55</leaders>
      </details>
      <details>
         <locale>657</locale>
         <teammates>55</teammates>
         <leaders>66</leaders>
      </details>
      <trainers>
         <trainer>
            <empID>User1234</empID>
         </trainer>
      </trainers>
   </segment>
   <segment>
      <segmentDate>03/13/2015</segmentDate>
      <hours>4</hours>
      <details>
         <locale>653</locale>
         <teammates>3</teammates>
         <leaders>4</leaders>
      </details>
      <details>
         <locale>655</locale>
         <teammates>44</teammates>
         <leaders>55</leaders>
      </details>
      <details>
         <locale>657</locale>
         <teammates>55</teammates>
         <leaders>66</leaders>
      </details>
      <trainers>
         <trainer>
            <empID>User1234</empID>
         </trainer>
      </trainers>
   </segment>
</root>'

-- Declare our temp tables
DECLARE @tmpSeg TABLE (teSegmentID INT, trainingEventID INT, segmentDate DATE, nonProdHrs int);
DECLARE @tmpEvents TABLE (teSegmentID INT IDENTITY(1,1), trainingEventID INT, segmentDate DATE, nonProdHrs INT);

-- First, Insert the main segments
INSERT INTO @tmpEvents(trainingEventID, segmentDate, nonProdHrs)
OUTPUT Inserted.teSegmentID, Inserted.trainingEventID, Inserted.segmentDate, Inserted.nonProdHrs INTO @tmpSeg
SELECT ParamValues.x1.value('../trainingEventID[1]', 'INT'),
       ParamValues.x1.value('(segmentDate/text())[1]', 'DATE'),
       ParamValues.x1.value('(hours/text())[1]', 'INT')
FROM   @xml.nodes('/root/segment') AS ParamValues(x1);

SELECT * FROM @tmpSeg

-- Now, we join on our temp table and insert the Segment Details
SELECT s.teSegmentID,
ParamValues.x1.value('(details/locale/text())[1]', 'INT') AS localeID,
ParamValues.x1.value('(details/teammates/text())[1]', 'INT') AS teammates,
ParamValues.x1.value('(details/leaders/text())[1]', 'INT') AS leaders,
ParamValues.x1.value('(../trainingEventID/text())[1]', 'INT') AS eventID,
ParamValues.x1.value('(segmentDate/text())[1]', 'DATE') AS date,
ParamValues.x1.value('(hours/text())[1]', 'INT') AS hours
FROM @tmpSeg AS s
INNER JOIN @xml.nodes('/root/segment') AS ParamValues(x1)
ON s.trainingEventID = ParamValues.x1.value('(../trainingEventID/text())[1]', 'INT')
AND s.segmentDate = ParamValues.x1.value('(segmentDate/text())[1]', 'DATE')
AND s.nonProdHrs = ParamValues.x1.value('(hours/text())[1]', 'INT')
```

As you can see from the XML structure, it is broken down into parts. There is a `segment` and then within the segment there can be multiple `Details` Nodes.

The first step in the query is to create all of the segments which appears to be working fine. Each segment gets created and the Identity is stored in a temp table from the output.

Next, I need to create records for each details node using the Identity of its parent segment. I do this by joining the temp table from the output some some of its data to get the details needed.

The issue with this is due to multiple `details` nodes, it is only accessing the first one and storing its data.

The output in the last statement using this example should contain 9 records. There are 3 `details` nodes for each segment and there are 3 segments total.

Not sure how to accomplish this but its driving me crazy.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Unless I am missing something, you are selecting the first value from the returned Xpath eery time you do [1]. Where would you expect to get [2]?

Comment: In the second part of the query where I am just selecting the output and joining the tmpTable it is only accessing the first details node where there are 3 total per segment. The issue is coming from this piece of code I believe `INNER JOIN @xml.nodes('/root/segment') AS ParamValues(x1)` as Its joining on the segment level and then looking in `details`. However, its only looking in the first details node it finds even though there is more than one.

Comment: The end result should be creating 3 segments (its currently doing this) but then in a separate table, 9  "details" records that reference the Identity of their parent segment in the segments table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need another level for details, first off, but there's also the question of trainers..I took a bit of liberty with the solution here, so feel free to modify as needed.

```
    DECLARE @xml xml = '<root>
   <trainingEventID>572</trainingEventID>
   <segment>
      <segmentDate>03/03/2015</segmentDate>
      <hours>4</hours>
      <details>
         <locale>653</locale>
         <teammates>3</teammates>
         <leaders>4</leaders>
      </details>
      <details>
         <locale>655</locale>
         <teammates>44</teammates>
         <leaders>55</leaders>
      </details>
      <details>
         <locale>657</locale>
         <teammates>55</teammates>
         <leaders>66</leaders>
      </details>
      <trainers>
         <trainer>
            <empID>User12341</empID>
         </trainer>
      </trainers>
   </segment>
   <segment>
      <segmentDate>03/04/2015</segmentDate>
      <hours>4</hours>
      <details>
         <locale>653</locale>
         <teammates>3</teammates>
         <leaders>4</leaders>
      </details>
      <details>
         <locale>655</locale>
         <teammates>44</teammates>
         <leaders>55</leaders>
      </details>
      <details>
         <locale>657</locale>
         <teammates>55</teammates>
         <leaders>66</leaders>
      </details>
      <trainers>
         <trainer>
            <empID>User1234</empID>
         </trainer>
      </trainers>
   </segment>
   <segment>
      <segmentDate>03/13/2015</segmentDate>
      <hours>4</hours>
      <details>
         <locale>653</locale>
         <teammates>3</teammates>
         <leaders>4</leaders>
      </details>
      <details>
         <locale>655</locale>
         <teammates>44</teammates>
         <leaders>55</leaders>
      </details>
      <details>
         <locale>657</locale>
         <teammates>55</teammates>
         <leaders>66</leaders>
      </details>
      <trainers>
         <trainer>
            <empID>User1234</empID>
         </trainer>
      </trainers>
   </segment>
</root>'

-- Declare temp tables
DECLARE @tmpSeg TABLE (teSegmentID INT IDENTITY(1,1), trainingEventID INT, segmentDate DATE, nonProdHrs INT, trainer varchar(30));
DECLARE @tmpLocales TABLE (teSegmentID INT, trainingEventID INT/*, segmentDate DATE, nonProdHrs int*/, locale int, teammates int, leaders int);
DECLARE @tmpTrainers TABLE (teSegmentID INT, trainingEventID INT, empID VARCHAR(30));

-- Get Segment info
INSERT INTO @tmpSeg(trainingEventID, segmentDate, nonProdHrs, trainer)
SELECT 
      ParamValues.x1.value('../trainingEventID[1]', 'INT')
    , ParamValues.x1.value('segmentDate[1]', 'DATE')
    , ParamValues.x1.value('hours[1]', 'INT')
    , ParamValues.x1.value('trainers[1]/trainer[1]/empID[1]', 'VARCHAR(30)')
FROM   @xml.nodes('/root/segment') AS ParamValues(x1);

SELECT * FROM @tmpSeg

-- Get Segment-dependent trainer info
INSERT INTO @tmpTrainers(teSegmentID, trainingEventID, empID)
SELECT
        S.teSegmentID
      , D.trainingEventID
      , D.empID
FROM (
    SELECT
          ParamValues.x1.value('empID[1]', 'VARCHAR(30)') AS empID
        , ParamValues.x1.value('../../../trainingEventID[1]', 'INT') AS trainingEventID
        , ParamValues.x1.value('../../segmentDate[1]', 'DATE') AS segmentDate
        , ParamValues.x1.value('../../hours[1]', 'INT') AS nonProdHours
    FROM @xml.nodes('/root/segment/trainers/trainer') AS ParamValues(x1)
    ) D
    INNER JOIN @tmpSeg S ON D.trainingEventID = S.trainingEventID
        AND D.segmentDate = S.segmentDate
        AND D.nonProdHours = S.nonProdHrs

SELECT * FROM @tmpTrainers

-- Get segment-dependent locale info
INSERT INTO @tmpLocales
SELECT
        S.teSegmentID
      , D.trainingEventID
      , D.locale
      , D.teammates
      , D.leaders
FROM (
    SELECT
          ParamValues.x1.value('locale[1]', 'INT') AS locale
        , ParamValues.x1.value('teammates[1]', 'INT') AS teammates
        , ParamValues.x1.value('leaders[1]', 'INT') AS leaders
        , ParamValues.x1.value('../../trainingEventID[1]', 'INT') AS trainingEventID
        , ParamValues.x1.value('../segmentDate[1]', 'DATE') AS segmentDate
        , ParamValues.x1.value('../hours[1]', 'INT') AS nonProdHours
    FROM @xml.nodes('/root/segment/details') AS ParamValues(x1)
    ) D
    INNER JOIN @tmpSeg S ON D.trainingEventID = S.trainingEventID
        AND D.segmentDate = S.segmentDate
        AND D.nonProdHours = S.nonProdHrs

SELECT *
FROM @tmpLocales
```

Comment: This worked perfectly! Thank you for your additional thoughts on the trainers, that's exactly the route I was going as well.

Answer (score 0):

Your last `SELECT` is still iterating through the `<segment>` nodes, of which there are only 3. You need to shed it to the `<details>` level by using another `CROSS APPLY`:

```
-- Now, we join on our temp table and insert the Segment Details
SELECT s.teSegmentID,
D.Detail.value('locale[1]', 'INT') AS localeID,
D.Detail.value('teammates[1]', 'INT') AS teammates,
D.Detail.value('leaders[1]', 'INT') AS leaders,
ParamValues.x1.value('(../trainingEventID/text())[1]', 'INT') AS eventID,
ParamValues.x1.value('(segmentDate/text())[1]', 'DATE') AS date,
ParamValues.x1.value('(hours/text())[1]', 'INT') AS hours
FROM @tmpSeg AS s
INNER JOIN @xml.nodes('/root/segment') AS ParamValues(x1)
CROSS APPLY ParamValues.x1.nodes('details') AS D(Detail)
ON s.trainingEventID = ParamValues.x1.value('(../trainingEventID/text())[1]', 'INT')
AND s.segmentDate = ParamValues.x1.value('(segmentDate/text())[1]', 'DATE')
AND s.nonProdHrs = ParamValues.x1.value('(hours/text())[1]', 'INT')
```